# Formulas disappeared when values copied

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet called **data** where I perform my calculations using various formulas. I create a new sheet called **summary** and *copy-paste* the calculated *values* from my **data** sheet into my **summary** sheet using *Paste Special*. I save the file and after 30 minutes of further work on **summary** sheet I realise that all the *formulas* in the **data** sheet are *replaced with the values*. Restoring the formulas using *Undo* is impossible. How can I restore them and why did the original formulas disappear in the first place?

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Sorry for that, the situation is really weird, but I was thinking someone may have had the problem too and found a solution

Comment: I would guess this has to do with a corrupt source (data) file or a unique bug. I've certainly never heard of or observed it happening myself in my years of IT work. What version of Excel? Have you been able to duplicate the issue?

Answer (score -1):

If you selected "Values" from the "Paste Special" dialogue box then you will have pasted the results of the formulas, not the formulas themselves.

I'm not sure if you can get back from this, but try the following:

- Save your work and exit the file
- Make a copy of the file, open the copy and verify it looks good, then close it again - **THIS IS IMPORTANT**, if the rest of this doesn't work then at least you can go back to this copy
- Open the original file again
- Highlight the area with the formulas on the original sheet and copy them
- Highlight where you pasted on the new sheet
- Use "Paste Special" but this time select "Formulas" then click "OK"

If this doesn't work, remember you can use Undo (Ctrl+z) to back out the paste and then you can try again, choosing some other option from the "Paste Special" dialogue box.
Don't be afraid to experiment because you have got your back-up copy of the file if things get really messed up.

Good luck :)

Nick

Comment: The pasted results being values are totally fine. My problem is that the *original formulas* that I copied were replaced *in-place* by their values. This is very unsettling and the only explanation for me is: I may have accidentally pasted the values back to where I copied them from, replacing the formulas.

Comment: Please read the question. Op made it pretty clear this isn't the case.

Comment: @music2myear and Arthur Khazbs - my apologies, I have re-read the Op and realise my foolish mistake.

Comment: Now that I properly understand, I do not have an answer, however I have encountered similar behaviour in LibreOffice Calc: When entering data into sheet2 I later find the data duplicated into sheet1, the significant thing here is that sheet2 was initially created by making a copy of sheet1, is it possible that making a copy of a sheet creates some sort of link between them?

Answer (score -2):

Paste Special values only include the text from your formulas, If you wish to paste the formulas into a different worksheet/workbook, use the paste formulas option (highlighted in yellow).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljIPu.png)

This paste option will allow you to paste formulas without altering the text in other cells.

Have you tried opening unsaved files?